# Losing pointer data after function ends

Tags: c++, pointers, vector

i'm trying to make a pointer points to some vector but after the function ends the debugger shows that the pointer is not pointing to that anymore.
The relevant code is below:

```
#pragma once
#include "Configuration.h"
#include "Enemy.h"

class FireBall:public sf::Sprite{
public:
    FireBall(const sf::Vector2f position,  Tile * startTile);
    void moveFB();
    void setTrail(vector<Tile *> *trail);
    void removeTrail();

private:
    sf::Vector2f _position;
    vector<Tile *> *_p2_trail;
    vector<Tile *>::iterator _it2Tile;
    sf::Clock _clock;
    int _lastMoveTime;

    float getDecimalPart(float number);
};


void FireBall::setTrail(vector<Tile *> *trail){
    _p2_trail = trail; // here it points to the vector (SHOULED REMAIN LIKE THAT AFTER FUNCTION ENDS....)
    _it2Tile = _p2_trail->begin(); // setting iterator to begin
}


void GameBoard::setFireBall(bool set, float x, float y){
    if (set)
        _p2FB = new FireBall(sf::Vector2f((float)x*OFFSET,(float)y*OFFSET),        _gameBoard[x][y]);
    else{
        _p2FB->removeTrail();
        delete _p2FB;
    }

    _hasFireBall = set;
    _p2FB->setTrail(&_player->getTrail());
    // at this point _p2FB no more points to the vecotr! why?!!
}
```

Player header:
    #pragma once
    #include "Configuration.h"
    #include "Character.h"

```
class Player:public Character{
public:
    Player(vector< vector <Tile *>> &gameBoard, const sf::Vector2f position, const     IMAGE img);
    bool isLegalMove(const sf::Vector2f &position);
    void move(sf::Vector2f &direction, Tile ** previousTile, Tile ** currentTile);
    void act();

    void setShielded(const bool shieldMode){ _sheilded = shieldMode; };
    bool getShielded() const {return _sheilded; };
    vector<Tile *> getTrail(){ return _trail; };
    void addToTrail(Tile * tile);
    void convertTrailToShield();
    void removeTrail();
    void fixBoardPosition();
    void updateShielded(const pair<int,int>& prevPosition);
private:
    bool _sheilded;
    vector<Tile *> _trail;
```

};

Comment: Please show the definitions of _player, _player->getTrail()

Comment: what does `player->getTrail()` does? can you include the code too?

Comment: I've included Player header file.. getTrail() returns the vector

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Player::getTrail() returns a temporary object of type "vector" and you take its pointer and stores with the _p2FB->setTrail() call. The lifetime of the temporary is only till the end of the expression in this case. So, the pointer Fireball::_p2_trail is invalid just after the setTrail call.

Comment: +1, nice catch. I saw the '*' in the signature and though it was returning a pointer. Instead, it should be: `vector<Tile *> *getTrail(){ return &_trail; };`

Comment: @Brady : I find this feature bit annoying, why can't the standard keep the scope of these type of variables just like for a local variable? I can see that it is a waste of space, but not sure if that is the answer

Answer (score 1):

In `setFireBall()` if `set` is false, you delete the `_p2FB`, and then 2 lines later you use it by calling `setTrail()`. You're calling a method on a deleted pointer.

Also, Is the game multi-threaded? Could it be that a different thread is modifying/removing the player's vector in between when you get a pointer to it and when the debugger says its invalid?

Comment: No i'm not reaching there (yet), I've set the debug breakpoint right after _p2FB->setTrail(&_player->getTrail());
and its not pointing to the vector anymore

Comment: By the time you get to the last line of `setFireBall()` when `set` is false, the `_p2FB` instance is no longer valid because you already delete it.

Comment: no its not multi-threaded.. You were right about deleting and then using it, but thats not my problem now , i moved the line:
_p2FB->setTrail(&_player->getTrail());
into the if(set){ } block...
But it didnt fix the problem ..

Comment: @etaiso, using the debugger, check if the vector is still "valid" after setting the iterator in setTrail()

Comment: nope, neither the vector pointer and iterator are invalid... but the problem is with the vector's pointer.. i removed the iterator line for now trying to figure out why the vector is invalid ..

Answer (score 0):

if your constructor calling the set trail, then instead of setting the vector on the stack,
try putting it in the heap and pass a pointer.
It's good practice to work with pointer with object on the heap and not on the stack.
if it's on the stack and you try to save a pointer to it, it will be freed when its scope ends.

Comment: The constructor isn't calling setTrail.. what you mean is that i need to store the _trail at heap ?
like vector<Tile *> *_trail;
and then do something like _trail = new vector..... ?